# puma plus bundler: launch app using pumactl, but bundler aware

Tags: rubygems, sinatra, bundler, puma

I'm creating a Puma/Sinatra app and would like to use bundler to manage gem versions.  I have a Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, etc.  I can launch my app via:

```
bundle exec puma -C config.rb
```

But I'd also like to set up an init.d script to run the app as a service, and for that I was planning to use `pumactl`.  However, when I start the app using `pumactl` it seems not to care about bundler:

```
pumactl -F config.rb start
```

I tested this by requiring ActiveRecord 5.0+ in my Gemfile, running `bundle install`, manually removing ActiveRecord 5.0.0.1, then launching the app via pumactl.  It picked up a 4.x version of ActiveRecord.

Is there a way to use pumactl in conjunction with bundler so that the app will get the gem versions specified in Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bundle exec pumactl -F config.rb start
```